# If $S$ is skew-hermitian, show that $iS$ is hermitian.

Tags: matrices

I'm assuming that $S$ is skew-hermitian, and I'm able to show that that implies that $S^2$ is Hermitian, I'm hoping to combine these 2 equation in some fashion to show that $iS$ is hermitian, but nothing seems to work

Comment: No, a skew-Hermitian $S$ is in general not Hermitian. But $iS$ in fact is. Start with $(iS)^* = \ldots$

Comment: Sorry meant that I can show it implies $S^2$ is hermitian

Answer (score 1):

$$ (iS)^* = -i S^* = (-i) (-S) = iS
$$
Therefore $iS$ is Hermitian.
$$ (S^2)^* = S^* S^* = (-S)(-S) = S^2
$$
Therefore $S^2$ is Hermitian.

Comment: lol i was just typing this

Comment: @Henry W. That's so simple. Don't you think the OP could have seen that him/herself?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp The OP says that nothing seems to work, so I don't know any other information I could put here.

Comment: It's not clear to me that you can multiply out a scalar and change the sign

Comment: @HenryW. Well, something like "What is the adjoint of $\lambda A$ when $\lambda$ is a numer", for example. However, now it's done.

Comment: @Kristaps John Balodis The distributive property of conjugation: $\overline{zw} = \overline{z} \cdot \overline{w}$.

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis $\langle \lambda Ax,y\rangle = \ldots = \langle x,?y\rangle$

Comment: Thanks!  I knew of that rule, I guess it just slipped my mind that it works when matrices and scalars are together

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp , I think I see what you're trying to say but I don't think that helps because that Lemma about moving A over and conjugate-transposing it is only when x and y are vectors

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis That's the point. It holds for all vectors. For all vectors $x,y$ we have $\langle x,(\lambda A)^*y\rangle = \langle\lambda Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,\overline\lambda A^* y\rangle$. This proves $(\lambda A)^* = \overline\lambda A^*$.

Comment: Oh, ok got it, thanks.